# SQL Join two tables and select a matching record at random from the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a user table, and a MyPhotos table. The UserTable contains a UserID column and other columns pertaining to user information. The MyPhotos tables contains UserID and ImageFile columns.

The MyPhotos table can have multiple records for a single UserID. I need a way to find the total number of photos for a particular user, along with **ONE** image file that is **randomly** selected for each UserID.

The SQL statement I am currently using returns the same image every time instead of a random image. Here it is:

```
SELECT  MyPhotos.UserID, 
        UsrTbl.ScreenName, COUNT(*) AS TotalPhotos, 
        MAX(MyPhotos.ImagesFileName) AS Expr1
FROM MyPhotos 
INNER JOIN UsrTbl ON MyPhotos.UserID = UsrTbl.AccountID
GROUP BY MyPhotos.UserID, UsrTbl.ScreenName
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually like setting up a couple test tables in tempdb so that you can play around with the solution.  I did not add any integrity to the design since you have the real tables.

```
-- Just playing
use Tempdb;
Go

--
-- Table 1
--

-- Remove table
if OBJECT_ID('MyPhotos') > 0
drop table MyPhotos
go

-- Simple photo table
create table MyPhotos
(
UserID int,
ImagesFileName varchar(64)
);

-- Some data
insert into MyPhotos values
(1, 'c:\pics\fee.jpg'),
(1, 'c:\pics\fi.jpg'),
(1, 'c:\pics\foo.jpg'),
(1, 'c:\pics\fumb.jpg'),
(2, 'c:\pics\huff.jpg'),
(2, 'c:\pics\n.jpg'),
(2, 'c:\pics\puff.jpg');

-- Show the data
select * from MyPhotos


--
-- Table 2
--

-- Remove table
if OBJECT_ID('UsrTbl') > 0
drop table UsrTbl
go

-- Simple photo table
create table UsrTbl
(
AccountID int,
ScreenName varchar(64)
);

-- Some data
insert into UsrTbl values
(1, 'Jolly Green Giant'),
(2, 'Big Bad Wolf');

-- Show the data
select * from UsrTbl;
```

One way to solve the problem is to use Common Table Expressions.

```
--
-- Grab a random pic by user id
-- 

;
WITH ctePhotos 
as
(
    SELECT 
      UserID, ImagesFileName, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID) as ImgNo
    FROM 
      MyPhotos 
),
cteRandomPick
AS
(
    SELECT UserID, CEILING(RAND() * MAX(ImgNo)) AS ImgNo
    FROM ctePhotos
    GROUP BY UserId
)
SELECT 
  p.UserId,
  u.ScreenName,
  p.ImgNo,
  p.ImagesFileName
FROM UsrTbl as u INNER JOIN ctePhotos as p ON u.AccountID = p.UserID
INNER JOIN cteRandomPick as r ON p.UserID = r.UserID and p.ImgNo = r.ImgNo;
```

The ctePhones just enumerates the pictures, image number by user id.  The cteRandomPick grabs the max 
image number and multiplies it by the RAND() function to get a random picture.

Last but not least, the body joins the two CTE's and the User Table to get your result.

If you run the code multiple times, you get different picks.

[image]

Comment: +1 I used your DDL+INSERT scripts to test my solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Cool and many thanks. I added SELECT UserID, CEILING(RAND() * MAX(ImgNo)) AS ImgNo, COUNT(*) AS TotalPhotos  to get total count of photos submitted by a user. Perfect solution for a datalist that shows total photos submitted by a user as well as a randomly selected image for that user.